# How to add more values to array on button click in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to add values to array on button click.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$user_hand = [];
$dealer_hand = [];

$rand = mt_rand(0, 15);

if(isset($_POST['posh'])){
    array_push($user_hand, $rand);
}

print_r($user_hand);

?>

<form method="post"><input type="submit" name="posh"></form>
```

What I am achieving atm is `Array ([0] => 11)`, while I want to achieve this after 3 times clicking the button: `Array ([0] => 11, [1] => 4, [2] => 6)`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you want your value to persist across multiple page loads then you'll need to persist it somewhere.  Session state, a database, a form value, a cookie, etc.

Comment: Aah okay, would it be stupid to update database table for each $_POST? It is for a blackjack game where the user is probably pushing $_POST about 20 times a minute

Comment: If a database is where you want to store your data then it certainly wouldn't be stupid to update the database when the data changes.  If you encounter performance issues then there are a variety of ways to address them.  You could use AJAX instead of an entire form POST to minimize the network traffic.  You could hold a game in session state until the game is complete and then only save the results of the game to the database.  Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
// start session to add/update/read session variables
session_start();

// create empty array if key is not present in session
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_hand'])) {
    $_SESSION['user_hand'] = [];
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['dealer_hand'])) {
    $_SESSION['dealer_hand'] = [];
}

$rand = mt_rand(0, 15);

// push value in session variable or array
if(isset($_POST['posh'])){
    array_push($_SESSION['user_hand'], $rand);
}

print_r($_SESSION['user_hand']);
// Optional but recommended to close session for writing as we don't want to update session data anymore
session_write_close(); 
?>

<form method="post"><input type="submit" name="posh"></form>
```

This should fix your issue.